# How to get combinations of a vector

Tags: c++, combinations

I am trying to implement a function to get all combinations of a vector in C++.
The following code is my function:

```
std::set<std::vector<int>> power_set(std::vector<int> original_list) {
    std::set<std::vector<int>> sets;

    if (original_list.empty()) {
         sets.insert({});

         return sets;
    }

    std::vector<int> lst(original_list.begin(), original_list.end());
    int head = lst[0];
    std::vector<int> rest(lst.begin() + 1, lst.end());

    for (std::vector<int> lst2 : power_set(rest)) {
        std::vector<int> new_lst;
        new_lst.push_back(head);
        new_lst.insert(new_lst.end(), lst2.begin(), lst2.end());
        sets.insert(new_lst);
        sets.insert(lst2);
    }

    return sets;
}
```

However, it seems that the for loop doesn't execute. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah How would you use permutations here? The power set has size `2^n`, the number of permutations are `n!`...

Comment: So one thing you seem to be assuming is that `sets.insert({});` will insert something into the set.  But it doesn't: https://onlinegdb.com/5zhP44A5u  Maybe you wanted `sets.insert({{}});`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah That solved it. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Great catch. I wonder if the benefits from having overload on `std::initializer_list` outweight the gotcha moments like this

Comment: I think that I had better leave answering to someone else.  Explaining std::initializer_list and overload resolution is not that easy...  @Yksisarvinen I caught it this time because it always bites me...